# Two identical servers, one of them have 2x CPU load

Tags: freebsd, cpu-usage, vmstat

Http requests are splitted 50/50 between two servers. Servers are running FreeBSD 9.2, their hardware, software & application configurations are absolutely identical. But one of servers is getting 2x CPU load. During traffic peaks this fact causes LA problems on "buggy" server.

Both servers are nginx+php-fpm+redis+memcached+mysql setup and have nothing beside that. Have no any crons running etc.

```
CPU: 24.9% user,  0.0% nice,  8.1% system,  0.0% interrupt, 66.9% idle
CPU: 12.7% user,  0.0% nice,  3.4% system,  0.0% interrupt, 83.9% idle
```

`vmstat 1` for buggy server

```
 procs      memory      page                   disk   faults         cpu
 r b w     avm    fre   flt  re  pi  po    fr  sr mf0   in   sy   cs us sy id
44 0 0  78511M  3775M    92   0   0   0    93   9   0   27   82   37 12  5 83
14 0 0  78539M  3768M  3612   0   0   0  2320   0  94 4019 290766 59170 32 42 26
10 0 0  78544M  3763M  1019   0   0   0   544   0 127 4054 267760 36825 26  8 67
11 0 0  78540M  3758M  2156   0   0   0  2106   0 218 4045 272843 37923 28  8 64
 9 0 0  78544M  3759M   601   0   0   0  1412   0  55 4067 279558 37887 26  9 65
 9 0 0  78548M  3753M  1835   0   0   0   414   0  79 4042 273963 37264 26  9 65
11 0 0  78548M  3754M  1036   0   0   0  2934   0 199 4078 262876 36150 25  7 68
 9 0 0  78548M  3759M   295   0   0   0  2408   0  44 3781 249391 32801 25  7 68
15 1 0  78548M  3758M  2158   0   0   0  2628   0 100 3816 250708 33943 25  7 68
12 0 0  78552M  3754M  1506   0   0   0  1637   0 113 3965 269543 36864 28  8 64
 9 0 0  78564M  3746M  2288   0   0   0   620   0 102 3974 256959 34928 26  8 67
13 0 0  78568M  3745M   689   0   0   0   939   0  75 3992 272804 36572 25  9 66
13 0 0  78568M  3744M   239   0   0   0  2084   0  44 4040 273036 36631 26  8 65
 8 0 0  78479M  3752M  2279   0   0   0  5177   0 128 3955 263155 36118 27  9 64
 9 0 0  78475M  3752M   496   6   0   0  1085   0 172 3954 256552 34906 25  8 67
15 0 0  78475M  3754M   263   0   0   0  2016   0 178 3870 254864 35432 25  8 67
```

`vmstat 1` for good server

```
 procs      memory      page                   disk   faults         cpu
 r b w     avm    fre   flt  re  pi  po    fr  sr mf0   in   sy   cs us sy id
 1 0 6  78873M  4870M   153   2   0   0    54  61   0   48   48  136  6  1 93
 6 0 6  78865M  4871M   755   0   0   0  1839   0 126 3588 254715 30931 13  3 84
 7 0 6  78873M  4868M   715   0   0   0  3750   0  76 3453 240474 28698 11  4 85
 6 0 6  78869M  4867M   404   0   0   0  1793   0 165 3419 232270 27453 12  3 85
 5 0 6  78877M  4867M   213   0   0   0   845   0 276 3793 261560 31747 13  3 84
 4 0 6  78877M  4866M   602   0   0   0   830   0 157 3539 249173 29895 12  4 84
 5 1 6  78881M  4858M  1762   0   0   0  1639   0  93 3586 256812 30538 12  4 84
 4 0 6  78890M  4851M  1757   0   0   0 90059   0  88 3651 267225 32082 13  3 83
 4 0 6  78890M  4845M   836   0   0   0 12182   0 202 3822 259947 31564 12  4 85
 5 0 6  78894M  4842M   726   0   0   0   906   0 314 3665 247476 30474 12  3 85
 5 0 6  78898M  4832M   638   0   0   0   288   0 258 3698 252603 31849 13  3 84
 5 0 6  78902M  4818M  1231   0   0   0  1992   0 460 3815 247440 31429 12  3 84
 9 0 6  78902M  4808M    23   0   0   0   152   0 596 4121 252113 31974 12  3 85
 6 0 6  78902M  4804M  1050   1   0   0   885   0 206 3810 265230 32513 13  4 83
```

We can see something interesteing in `procs.r` and `proces.w` columns. Buggy server have no `w` processes at all, but it have bigger number of `r` processes. How can I interpret this? What metrics should I get to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure load is evenly distributed between the two servers? You could check the nginx logs to verify that they're both getting the same number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that one of them is loaded more, maybe you distributed the number of requests equally, but "buggy" one gets more demanding requests, it has more running processes and more page faults. Take a vmstat and check what they actually was serving at this moment.